# very well sync programming editor for both of osx and windows 7

Tags: windows, macos, editor

While I use an editplus on windows 7 and a smultron on OSX, very annoying things happen all the time. I mean, it is okay on OSX, but when I use the same file on windows 7, the line is different and everything is messed up. I do not know what happened.

Is there any good programming editor on both operating system without any misalignment things?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a Windows editor that supports OSX end of line encodings. As an example the Zeus editor can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix/Windows use different character sequences for determining line breaks. To fix your issue, you need to set both editors to use the same sequence, for example in smultron you can change "Line Endings" parameter to 'Dark Side (CRLF)'.